# Using window.myVar

Tags: javascript

I am trying to integrate into my website the colorWheel picker, (not the color picker) from [this color picker](http://www.dematte.at/colorPicker/). I started checking out the source JavaScript code, [index.js](https://github.com/PitPik/colorPicker/blob/master/index.js), and I don't know whether I should add this code to my website.

[index.js Line 15](https://github.com/PitPik/colorPicker/blob/master/index.js#L15)

```
var ColorPicker = window.ColorPicker,
    Tools = ColorPicker || window.Tools
```

I think it's important, because they add events to `Tools`, but I don't know if I can just copy and paste the variables or I have to do some sort of setup before.

This is my first time seeing window.myVar. I google it, and it said it is a global variable. But I didn't see anywhere where they created it.

My question is, can I just copy and paste the code above? And what does that code actually do?

Comment: see comment in colorPicker.js, line 5: `// window.ColorPicker = { // comes from colorPicker.data.js and will be overwritten.` Sure enough, in colorPicker.data.js: `window.ColorPicker = { ... }`

Comment: @BrianDriscoll What about Tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this library, the variable `window` on line 15 is not the global window variable, but rather a variable defined in the function parameters.  It just so happens that the global `window` has been passed into this variable though.

```
(function(window) { // this window belongs to the function
  ...
})(window);  // the global window is passed to the anonymous function
```

Because the `ColorPicker` and `Tool` variables are defined in the scope of an anonymous function, the code snippet `var ColorPicker = window.ColorPicker, Tools = ColorPicker || window.Tools` does not override the global variables, `window.ColorPicker` and `window.Tool`.

```
(function(x) {
  var ColorPicker = x.ColorPicker,
      Tool = ColorPicker || x.Tools;
})(window);
```

Using the same code snippet in a global context (outside of a function) may potentially cause conflicts as `Tool = ColorPicker || window.Tools` will override the global variable `window.Tools` if `ColorPicker` is defined.  This may be undesirable.

Comment: Thanks! When `Tools` is created, there's a comment saying: "`provides functions like addEvent, ... getOrigin, etc.`". How can `Tools` provide those?

Comment: TBH, I don't think the global `window.Tools` is ever actually set anywhere in the library (I could be wrong).  The global `window.ColorPicker` is set in the file [colorPicker.js](https://github.com/PitPik/colorPicker/blob/master/colorPicker.js) on line 110.  So this means, `Tools` should always be `window.ColorPicker`.

Comment: Thanks! If I don't use the colorPicker.js file, what would I assign to Tools?

Answer (score 1):

this code tries to assign local variable colorpicker to be the colorpicker registered to the window object.

the highest scope of every javascript code is the window. if you open up developer tools and declare variable like `var a=5;` it will actually mean `window.a=5;`

so, this code tries to assign the global, already existent colorpicker to a local variable named colorpicker.
then, if `window.ColorPicker` was existent, it will assign it to a new variable called tools. if not (and left side of || is null or undefined), then it will assign the global variable `window.tools` to the local tools.

I say there's nothing bad with this code as long as you don't assign variables like 'tools' or 'colorpicker' to your own global window object, which may cause conflicts.

Comment: Thanks! If I don't use the colorPicker.js file, what would I assign to Tools?